# Emulate a focused page programmatically with a Chrome extension in JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, focus

I made a Chrome extension and I want it to make a specific tab think it's focused, even if it's not.

I know I can do it manually by opening Chrome DevTools panel and enabling "Emulate a focused page" but I really want my extension to do it programmatically.

Do you think it is possible ? Thx

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Some websites don't behave the same when the tab isn't focused, I simply want my extension to make their behavior consistent